# Web.xml error page with attributes

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

I am almost finished with an assignment but I have come into a problem. Bonus marks are given if we use web.xml to send error messages and that part works fine. However, I also need to send some attributes at the same time which the web.xml file seems to ignore.

I know you can just do request.setAttribute("exception", myException); but I should use web.xml.
I am using a requestdispatcher(also a requirement) to forward the request and response back. Is what I'm asking even possible?

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SomethingHere</display-name>
<!--   <welcome-file-list> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--   </welcome-file-list> -->

  <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
      <location>/myError.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your current `web.xml` file? It could help people to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: It's a basic web.xml file, nothing special... I added it in the question.

Comment: @dic19: how exactly is web.xml relevant here..? As stated in documentation and tutorials, OP just has to explicitly mark the JSP page in question as an error page in order have it to access those attributes. The web.xml is completely irrelevant then.

Comment: @BalusC that was a mistake by ignorance, sorry about that :( I did the review and I assumed if `web.xml` is in the title (and description) then it could be helpful. The point is show OP (as this is his/her first post) he/she should add anything that could be helpful to people to understand the problem.